# AngularJS calling service function via view

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with Angular(1.x) and just encountered a strange behaviour (which I do not exclude being a result of my code).

Here is the setup:

```
var module = angular.module('module_name');

module.service('service_name', function() {
    this.function_name = function() { ... }
});

module.controller('controller_name', ['$scope', 'service_name',
    function($scope, service_name) {

        $scope.function_name = function() { ... }
}])
```

And in the view :

```
<div ng-controller='controller_name'>
    <button ng-click="function_name()">Test</button>
</div>
```

The function in service_name is accessible in the controller via **service_name.function_name()** as expected. But here is the strange behaviour, (once again it occurs in a more complex setting, not saying this portion of code will reproduce the described scenario)

When clicking the button in the view the function called is not the **function_name from the controller** but the **function_name from the service**.

Eventhough they have the same name how can the view access a function directly in the service, shouldn't it be limited to its controller scope ?

Comment: You are corret, only the function_name from the controller should be getting called. We'll need to see a better code example where you're able to reproduce it in order to pinpoint why

Answer (score 2):

**This simply can not happen** unless and until somewhere in your code you write

```
$scope.function_name = service_name.function_name
```

> Services do not have any local scope.In angular view side on-click event expects
>   function in controller's (read local) scope.

What I suspect in your case is , As JS is all reference, You must be doing something like this in large file :

```
var dummy = service_name.function_name
...
$scope.function_name = dummy
```

Comment: Thank you for this confirmation. I checked the whole controller and **function_name** is not called once, it is only used from child directives. It is not even referenced as you described it

Comment: I am working on angular for a year now, pretty sure you it can not happen.  If you are still able to reproduce the bug, share the code. I would like to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to redefine the function name in your controller you can do something like this.

```
module.service('service_name', function() {
 this.function_name = function() { ... }

 return {
  function_name : function_name
 }
});

module.controller('controller_name', ['$scope', 'service_name',
  function($scope, service_name) {

  $scope.utils = service_name;
}]);
```

and then in your view call the function directly.

```
<div ng-controller='controller_name'>
  <button ng-click="utils.function_name()">Test</button>
</div>
```

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to give your controller and service name using for example
`abcCtrl` for controller and `abcService` for service and so on.

Why, because it will be easier for you to call it. and its not confusing

Comment: I'm following this standard, the point here is about the service scope being called from a view.